# Android : Parse xml data having different attribute in same tag

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm working on android application. here i have to parse data from the webservice. 
In the webservice the data is coming in this format.

```
<Result>
<Details Success="True"/>
<Detail pagelimit="384"/>
<Detail albumid="38569" albumname="Aashiq Faujaan" singername="Surjit Bhullar"     albumcover="http://i.pz10.com/music/album_art/1/38569.jpg"/>
<Detail albumid="38561" albumname="Sochea Vi Naa" singername="Surinderjit Maqsudpuri" albumcover="http://i.pz10.com/music/album_art/1/38561.jpg"/>
<Detail albumid="38555" albumname="Hitmaker – The Story So Far" singername="PBN" albumcover="http://i.pz10.com/music/album_art/1/38555.jpg"/>
<Detail albumid="38545" albumname="Angrezi Desi" singername="Akhil" albumcover="http://i.pz10.com/music/album_art/1/38545.jpg"/>
<Detail albumid="38544" albumname="Dil Vich (Single)" singername="Lucky Sidhu" albumcover="http://i.pz10.com/music/album_art/1/38544.jpg"/>
</Result>
```

This is the xml data that i 've to parse.

But here detail have only one attribute like this

```
<Detail pagelimit="384"/>
```

and after that Detail tag have 4 attribute like this

```
<Detail albumid="38569" albumname="Aashiq Faujaan" singername="Surjit Bhullar"     albumcover="http://i.pz10.com/music/album_art/1/38569.jpg"/>
```

Any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Simple xml framework for parsing your xml, With which you must define

```
root with @Root(name = "root_element_name", strict = false)
```

And

`xml elements with property @Element(required = false)`

Sp that in the bean object you will get default value of those elements wich are not present at runtime.

See the [tutorial for how to use simplexmlframework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php)

Hope that help.Thanks